# Admob requests working and 100% filled, not displayed in app

Tags: android, admob

Like the title says, I am requesting ads, they are being filled, but never displayed. I even enabled a house ad just to make sure. I have been screwing with this for 2 days now and cant find the solution. I am aware things changed recently with admob and attrs.xml is not longer required to make it work and now have a mess of code with no results. Any help would be appreciated!

Java code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //admob
        //AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14dd7f0258a8b7");
        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        re.setTesting(true);
        adView.loadAd(re);
        //end admob
    }
```

AndroidManifest.XML

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="false" 

    android:description="@string/description">
       <activity 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:name=".Index">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity 
                  android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<com.google.ads.AdView 
android:id="@+id/adView1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
ads:adSize="BANNER" 
ads:adUnitId="a14dd7f0258a8b7" 
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


(buttons here)
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: logCat =

```
05-22 15:57:22.882: WARN/Ads(294): Invalid adSize parameter in XML layout: -1. Defaulting to BANNER.
05-22 15:57:22.892: ERROR/Ads(294): AdView missing required XML attribute adUnitId.
05-22 15:57:23.512: INFO/Ads(294): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"u_sd":1.5,"u_w":480,"slotname":"a14dd7f0258a8b7","simulator":1,"msid":"com.robores.elect","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.4","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"4.0.4.android.com.robores.elect","hl":"en","u_h":800,"testing":1,"u_so":"p","u_audio":4});</script></head><body></body></html>
05-22 15:57:25.113: INFO/Ads(294): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?preqs=1&u_sd=1.5&u_w=480&slotname=a14dd7f0258a8b7&msid=com.robores.elect&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.0.4&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&format=320x50_mb&net=ed&app_name=4.0.4.android.com.robores.elect&hl=en&u_h=800&u_so=p&u_audio=4&adtest=on&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
05-22 15:57:25.763: INFO/global(294): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
05-22 15:57:25.913: DEBUG/dalvikvm(294): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6570 objects / 467056 bytes in 94ms
05-22 15:57:25.953: DEBUG/webviewglue(294): nativeDestroy view: 0x291bf8
05-22 15:57:25.953: DEBUG/webviewglue(294): nativeDestroy view: 0x291a40
05-22 15:57:26.513: WARN/webcore(294): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
05-22 15:57:26.563: INFO/Ads(294): onReceiveAd()
```

Comment: Try fill_parent, just to make sure your adview isn't getting hidden.

Comment: fill parent where? android:width-"fill parent"?

Comment: Just both on the adview, so there is no way it can be hidden.

Comment: Try getting rid of the XML (xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads", ads:adSize="BANNER" 
ads:adUnitId="a14dd7f0258a8b7" 
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"), think it might be borking on your BANNER as that is just a string rather than a reference. You're setting all those in java anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of the admob lib are you using. There are some difference between GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0.jar and GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.0.4.jar.

I recently updated from 4.0.4. to 4.1.0 and had to change some lines of code. Currently I've got almost exact the same code as you described above with no problems with 4.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_KEY);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_admob_layout);
            // Add the adView to it
            layout.addView(ad);
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
            request.setKeywords(MosaicCommon.AD_KEYWORDS);
```

You don't have the `addView(..)` part in yours.

Comment: that was causing force closes for me :/

Comment: don't need to add the AdView to a layout because it was from the main.xml

Answer (score 0):

Using the following , I fixed this error.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
 android:id="@+id/adView"
 android:layout_width="320dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:gravity="center"
 ads:adUnitId="my id goes here"
 ads:adSize="BANNER"
 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```